# Como fazer um upload para o Google Drive a partir do R

Tags: r, google-drive-api

Estava vendo sobre o package googledrive do CRAN do R e não estou conseguindo faze-lo funcionar, como faze-lo entrar na minha conta. Meu objetivo é upar um data frame e como CSV, direto para minha conta.

Comment: Boas Márccio. Não é uma resposta ao teu pedido, mas dá uma vista de olhos a estes dois links com um exemplo que talvez te ajudem no código do package googledrive caso ainda não tenhas visto. https://daattali.com/shiny/persistent-data-storage/
https://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/#gsheets Nestes links refere que segue o método semelhante ao que usou para ligar o dropbox
https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2#accessing-dropbox-on-shiny-and-remote-servers Não é a resposta, mas parece-me que talvez que ajudasse e fosse oportuno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá! Basta fazer o seguinte:

```
library(googledrive)
write.csv(mtcars, file = "dados.cars.csv") # Arquivo de exemplo para fazer o upload
googledrive::drive_upload(media = "/seu.diretorio/dados.cars.csv", 
                          path = "nome.do.arquivo.para.aparecer.no.drive.csv")
```

Se você colocar `type = spreadsheet` o teu arquivo vira uma planilha.

Ao fazer o primeiro upload, você terá que dar permissão da API do `googledrive`. A função `drive_update` atualiza o tipo de arquivo ou o metadata dele.

[Documentação Google drive](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/)